# Как подключить bytebuddy к android проекту

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь подключить byte buddy библиотеку к своему проекту в android studio. Я добавил dependency в gradle модуля:

```
implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.11.16'
```

Также в интернете я нашёл информацию, что для работы byte buddy на android необходимо прописать такую конструкцию:

```
ClassLoadingStrategy strategy = new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Wrapping(this.getDir(
                "generated",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

При этом класс ClassLoadingStrategy android studio находит, а AndroidClassLoadingStrategy вообще не видит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подключить byte buddy к android проекту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AndroidClassLoadingStrategy` находится в отдельном модуле

> implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.11.16'

https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/master/byte-buddy-android